# How to render a bibtext entry to a HTML bibliography using citation.js in gatsby?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prototype, gatsby, citations

I'm trying to render bibtext entries to formatted APA style HTML bibliographies with [citation.js](https://larsgw.github.io/citation.js/api/tutorial-cite_output.html) Everything works fine with the first instance of my `new Cite()` but my second instance output the result from the first :|

I am using Gatby.js so I load the citation.js script as a  tag with react-helmet and I work with the library in componentDidMount().

Here is the problem:

```
  componentDidMount() {  

    const Cite = require('citation-js')

    // create an instance of Cite
    const Cite1 = new Cite();

    // add the first bibtext entry
    Cite1.add(bibtext1);

    // create a bibliography
    const formatted1 = Cite1.format('bibliography', {
      format: 'html',
      template: 'apa'
    })

    // everything is great!!!
    console.log(Cite1); // output a Cite object with data from bibtext1 
    console.log(formatted1);// output a html block with data from bibtext1 



    // Same process here but with the second entry
    const Cite2 = new Cite();

    // this successfully add the second entry to the second Cite object
    Cite2.add(bibtext2);

    // create a second bibliography
    const formatted2 = Cite2.format('bibliography', {
      format: 'html',
      template: 'apa'
    })  

    console.log(Cite2);   // this output a Cite object with data from bibtext2 which is great,

    console.log(formatted2);  // But this output a html block with the data from bibtext1 
    //even though I used Cite2 which was a new instance of Cite with a different bibtext entry, why????

}
```

Comment: Hi, I am the author of the citation.js package. I am not seeing the same thing [on RunKit](https://runkit.com/larsgw/citation-js-double-output) but I *can* think of a reason why a bug like this would happen. What version of citation.js are you using? (output of `Cite.version`)

Comment: Hi @LarsW ! I am using `{cite: "0.5.0-alpha.4", citeproc: "1.2.32"}`

Comment: I changed the npm package for `npm i citation-js@0.4.9` and `Cite.version` now output `{cite: "0.4.9", citeproc: "1.2.32"}` but I still have the double output.

Comment: Hi @LarsW , any idea why this is happening? I saw there is a new release on npm `0.5.0-alpha.5` I tried it and it seems to be causing the same issue.

Comment: `0.5.0-alpha.5` is just one I forgot to publish earlier. The issue is likely caused by Citation.js trying to cache instances of [citeproc-js](https://github.com/Juris-M/citeproc-js)'s processing engine and I do see a problem now where if you make a new Cite instance with an item that has the same ID but different data, it shows the first one. I will fix that, but is that actually the problem in your data?

Comment: Yes you're right! Here is the data I was passing through: 
    `const bibtext1 =  
@article{article, title = {Caregivers’ experiences with the selection and use of assistive technology}, author = {Ben Mortenson}, year = {2018}, } ; `

`const bibtext2 = 
@article{article, title = {La marche du temps }, author = {J Hamann }, year = {2018}, }`

Comment: They have the same`article` id. I got these bibtex entries in a big concatenated file of entries. Should I just assign them unique ids?

Comment: @Frensoi: BibTeX relies on unique IDs, even outside of `citation.js`. You should definitely make all your BibTeX IDs unique.